# Can c++ array also leak memory?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, I was fearlessly experimenting until I saw the lecture on cs50 that memory leaks and this other stuff can crash my computer, I have programmed in PHP and javascript, where such things don't exist I guess, here is the program I wrote:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ifstream inFile;

ofstream outFile;

int size;

inFile.open("text.txt"); //Step 2

outFile.open("formated.out"); //Step 3
```

// here I am sending the file through PHP where the first line of the file is the number of lines in the file

```
inFile >> size;

size += 1;

string strArr[size];

for(int i = 0;i < size;i++){
    getline(inFile, strArr[i]);
}

string crntStr;
int sl;
string newStr;
for(int i = 1;i < size;i++){

    newStr = "";

    string crntStr = strArr[i];

    sl = crntStr.length();

    for(int j = 0;j < sl;j++){

        if(crntStr[j] == '<')
        newStr += "&lt;";
        else if(crntStr[j] == '>')
        newStr += "&gt;";
        else
        newStr += crntStr[j];

    }

    cout << newStr  << endl; 

    if(i != (size - 1))
    cout <<  "<br>";

}

    return 0;
}
```

My question is when I write a program of this sort should I be afraid of memory leaks, I compiled this program in devc++ and it was working fine but when I went to visual studio I got the following error:
c:\users\hamza\source\repos\hypertextformatting\hypertextformatting\hypertextformatting.cpp(32): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
 c:\users\hamza\source\repos\hypertextformatting\hypertextformatting\hypertextformatting.cpp(32): note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
 c:\users\hamza\source\repos\hypertextformatting\hypertextformatting\hypertextformatting.cpp(32): note: see usage of 'size'

Comment: This has nothing to do with a leak. You're using a variable length array feature that is non-standard C++ and does not exist in MSVC.

Comment: `string strArr[size];` is not valid standard c++. Variable length arrays are provided by some compilers as extentions.

Comment: VLAs are not standard C++ and note that dynamically allocating the array is not a replacement for VLAs. Use a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: Leaks typically come from using the new operator to allocate memory at run time, and failing to use the free operator to remove the memory when you are done with it. In general, just experimenting around with little programs won't cause major issues, the huge problems tend to arise when you have a reoccurring memory leak in a big program that runs semi indefinitely, as the memory leak will eventually cause the computer to run out of memory. But as far as experimenting and learning the language, it's something you should be aware of the possibility, but not be afraid of it happening.

Comment: @Ryan "failing to use the free operator" -> "failing to use the delete operator"

Comment: Going against the grain, I might say that though shan't be terrified of the leaks. As long as you understand what you are doing, and accept the fact that programs doesn't return memory until it exits, operating under 'never delete' rule has it's benefits. Although one might say this is not a leak at this point )

Comment: @SergeyA "understand what you are doing" is a really wide net you are casting here. TLB and cache performance implications can be far from trivial for example.

Comment: @Frank I fail to see how cache misses are related to 'never free' strategy.

Comment: Ok so as far as I understand main memory is volatile, so shouldn't shutting down my computer automatically free all allocated memory. isn't it kind of doing the same thing as delete operator.

Comment: @SergeyA [Here's](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/B0tXIs) a really hoky example. `x` would be less likely to be ejected from L1 if there was a `delete[] tmp` at the end of `bar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only memory allocation on the heap (or dynamic allocation) can lead to memory leaks. When you declare an array string strArr[size]; it will be placed on the stack and will be automatically "released" when program leaves current scope (stack pointer will decrease by strArr size) and desctructor will be called. Although the "string" objects data placed in dynamically alocated memory, it will be released by destructors. Memory leak is impossible here.
You can create a memory leak if you allocate memory in a heap by new, new[], malloc etc. call and forget to release the data after they are no longer needed.

So

```
string strArr[size]; // no leaks
string* strArr = new string[size]; //may be leak if you forget call delete[] strArr
```

Besides, variable length arrays is non-standard in C++ avoid using it!